# Why does stylelint ignore js files in ignoreFiles configuration?

Tags: css, stylelint

I don't understand why `stylelint` ignore `.js` files in [ignoreFiles](https://stylelint.io/user-guide/configure/#ignorefiles) configuration.

Since `stylelint` is a tool that helps you avoid errors and enforce conventions in your styles. So it should only focus on `.css`, `.less` and `.scss` files, why should I ignore `.js` files like this?

```json
{
  "ignoreFiles": ["**/*.js"]
}
```

Maybe it should ignore js files by default?

Answer (score 1):

Stylelint can extract styles from JavaScript objects and template literals.

There are many CSS-in-JS libraries, but the most widely used ones are [listed here](https://github.com/andreipfeiffer/css-in-js/blob/main/README.md#overview). Stylelint can lint the styles in most of these.